# how can i make view auto resize to fit to superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have 2 views

first is view1 size is 100x100

second is view2 size is 200 x200

my code is

```
[view1 addSubview:view2];
```

but size of view2 is greater than view1

how can i make view2 smaller to fit size of view1

thank you

Comment: try overriding layoutsubview. When you  change view hierarchy call [view1 setNeedsLayout]. it will call layoutsubview and there you can access each subView and resize it. read this. not exact but kind of helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4051465/919049

Comment: set the frame size of view 2 to be smaller than that of view1 using CGRectMake method...

Answer (score 3):

The modern way to achieve this is using auto layout. That way, no matter how your view rotates or changes, they'll stay the same size.

Depending on your setup, it'd be something like this

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];

[view1 addConstraints:@[widthConstraint,heightConstraint]];
```

If you need to target an earlier OS, set the frames equal and use `autoresizingMask`.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to fit bigger subview in smaller superview then:
 1. Make `size` of both the views same/equal.
 2. Make origin for subview as (0,0). As `frame` property takes view’s location in its superview’s coordinate system so for subview origin will be (0,0).

For your case you can do something like this:

```
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view1.frame.size.width, view1.frame.size.height)];  
[view1 addSubview:view2];
```

OR

```
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view1.bounds];  
[view1 addSubview:view2];
```

This is really beneficial when you want to shrink your bigger images (UIImageView) in smaller superviews (UIView).

Answer (score 1):

from [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

> Views can embed other views and create sophisticated visual hierarchies. This creates a parent-child relationship between the view being embedded (known as the subview) and the parent view doing the embedding (known as the superview). Normally, a subview’s visible area is not clipped to the bounds of its superview, but in iOS you can use the clipsToBounds property to alter that behavior. A parent view may contain any number of subviews but each subview has only one superview, which is responsible for positioning its subviews appropriately.

and from [`frame property reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame)

> The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system.

and from [`bounds property reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds)

> The bounds rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its own coordinate system
>   .

So you should setup your `view1.frame` or your `view2.bounds`

```
[view1 setBounds:CGRectMake(`x`,`y`,`width`,`height`)];
```

or

```
[view2 setFrame:CGRectmake(`x`,`y`,`width`,`height`)];
```

Comment: technically, the question asks how to do this with Auto Resize rather than using frames